# How to Check the checkbox when all the checkboxes in a row are checked?

Tags: jquery

Hi all How can i check the checkbox when all the other checkboxes in a row are checked what i mean is
i have a div table which looks like this

```
<div id="Row-8">
    <span class="span2">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="regular-checkbox" onchange="checkallrowcheckboxes(this)" value="8" name="selectedObjects" id="8"><label for="rowcommoncheckbox-8"></label></label></span>
    <span class="span2">AddOrEdit</span>
    <span class="span2">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="8" class="regular-checkbox" name="chkAdd" id="Add-8"><label for="Add-8"></label></label></span>
    <span class="span2">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="8" class="regular-checkbox" name="chkEdit" id="Edit-8"><label for="Edit-8"></label></label></span>
    <span class="span2">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="8" class="regular-checkbox" name="chkDel" id="Delete-8"><label for="Delete-8"></label></label></span>
    <span class="span2">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="8" class="regular-checkbox" name="chkview" id="View-8"><label for="View-8"></label></label></span>
</div>
```

Which looks like this

```
ChkColumn  PageName Chk1 Chk2 Chk3 Chk4
```

what i want is when all the checkboxes in right side os row are checked the left side checkbox should be automatically checked..i.e Chkcolumn should be automatically checked when Chk1 Chk2 Chk3 Chk4 are chekced..

Comment: It still doesn't make a whole lot of sense. What have you tried? Have you got a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mx4q2/

I added some 'driving'/'driven' classes to the checkboxes and then used this script:

```
function driveCheckbox(event){
    var $currentRow = $(this).parents('.row');

    var $checkedDrivers = $currentRow.find('.driving-checkbox:checked');
    if($checkedDrivers.length == 4){
        $currentRow.find('.driven-checkbox').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $currentRow.find('.driven-checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    }
}

function selectAll(event){

    var $currentRow = $(this).parents('.row');

    var $targets = $currentRow.find('.driving-checkbox');
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $targets.prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $targets.prop('checked', false);
    }
}
$('.driving-checkbox').change(driveCheckbox);
$('.driven-checkbox').change(selectAll);
```

​

Comment: All the driven-checkbox are checked in the div grid when i do that for a row

Comment: Updated again, now caters for multiple rows (see latest demo URL)

Answer (score 2):

Shameless self-promotion: this seems to be a perfect use-case for [a jQuery plugin I've written](http://mjball.github.com/jQuery-CheckAll/).

Try this:

```
$('#Row-8 input[type="checkbox"]:first')
    .checkAll('#Row-8 input[type="checkbox"]:not(:first)');​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/9ErH6

Comment: but if a user selects all the check box in the right the left check box should be checked no? but it is not happening.

Comment: I think they want something quite different to what you've demonstrated. It sounded like they want the 4 checkboxes on the right to drive the behaviour of the one on the left, rather than the one on the left driving the four on the right.

Comment: yes i want the left side checkbox to be checked when use selects all the checkboxes to his right on the screen

Comment: @SoftwareNerd updated for you. It's all in the selectors, and your markup means the selectors need to be a little more complicated `:)`

Comment: I dont Know the div id the ids are binded dynamically in a loop its actually a div grid if i  should say

Comment: @SoftwareNerd then you should be able use `.each()` to iterate over each div (assuming you want it to work in each div) and set up the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('#Row-8 input').change(function() {
        var add8 = $('#Add-8').is(':checked');
        var edit8 = $('#Edit-8').is(':checked');
        var delete8 = $('#Delete-8').is(':checked');
        var view8 = $('#View-8').is(':checked');
        if (add8 && edit8 && delete8 && view8) {
            $('#Row-8 input').attr('checked',false);
            $('#8').attr('checked',true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this is not based on a single div...there may several divs

Comment: They're all based on IDs, what do you mean? The way he had his html structured, this was the best I could do. I would ideally have the right 4 checkboxes in a group so that I can more easily reference them, cutting down the code needed for this to work.